# Построение графика PHP

Tags: php, графика

Нужно отрисовать график в картинку. Нашел только pChart и тот что то очень старый. Есть ли варианты?

Answer (score 2):

Google Charts вам в помощь.
https://developers.google.com/chart/

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__'/image.png', file_get_contents('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chxt=x,y&chs=700x400&chco=76A4FB,FF9900&chg=0,8.3333333&chdl=Visits|Unique%20visits&chls=3|3&chma=40,20,20,30&chxr=1,0,33411&chds=0,33411&chd=t%3A33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411|33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411,33411&chxl=0%3A|Jan-10|Feb-10|Mar-10|Apr-10|May-10|Jun-10|Jul-10|Aug-10|Sep-10|Oct-10|Nov-10|Dec-10'));
```

Comment: Подскажите как [такой](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart) график вывести?

Comment: Можете использовать враппер чтоб велосипед не изобретать.
https://github.com/pacbard/gChartPhp